# Where does the page Identifier set in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, porto-theme, store-id

We are using Porto theme and I want to echo the store id inside of the body tag as a extra class.

So for instance on our category page we get this:

```
< body data-container="body" class="page-with-filter page-products categorypath-gear-fitness-equipment category-fitness-equipment layout-1140 wide catalog-category-view page-layout-2columns-left" >
```

And i want to add inside of the class="" the extra "store id". But i don't know how this is set.
I think it's been set inside of the xml, but can't figure out where.

Can someone please help me, and if it has to be created with a module.. can you please explain how.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="store-id-add-here"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added CSS class in body tag using Plugin. Please follow this [link](https://nileshdubey.com/magento2/how-to-add-css-class-in-body/)

Comment: Hello Nilesh,

This is exactly what i mean. But when i do this, it does not work.
I think i have to add a registration.php .. but when i do that i get "There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace." 

So i think i did that wrong. When i add a etc/module.xml it removes the error. But it doen't work.

What did i screw up?

Comment: I need to see your code like what namespace you are using